# Programmatically create UIImage and UILabel based on HTML

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

i have a html string that's like:

[div][p]some text here[/p][img src=@"url"][b] here's image[/b][/div]

How can i programmatically create something like this:

(UILabel) some text here

(UIImage) display the image

(UILabel) (in bold)here's image

Important thing here is to parse the html content, get all paragraphs, brs, images, and then create uiimages and uilabels programmatically, calculating each one frame.

Sounds like a lot to do, but can someone give me an idea? Thank you! (PS I know how to programmatically add views)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use the [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead?

It has a method named `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` that you can use, to have it display HTML from a string.

Comment: Nope. Something like rich text uilabel

Comment: There is no such thing 'out of the box'. Give [TTTAtributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) and [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel) a look.

Comment: Can you explain, why you cannot use the `UIWebView`? It does al the formatting and displaying of images for you.

Comment: Well, can I embed it in my own view, with my own background, or i can just use it as separate view? Thanks mate

Comment: Yes you can. Have a look at [this image](http://settheclock.jetski-it.com/tmp/clock_en_1.png): the text saying _half past seven_ is an HTML string displayed in a UIWebView. It has a `clearColor` background so the image behind it shows through. UIWebView is your friend!